# Snowflake:Update all Procedures in one go

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Requirement: To update all the Procs in one go
Issue: Its tedious to get_ddl for all procs and update it

Currently, every stored proc has one issue as the example below

```
`from schema.tableA:`
```

Need to be replaced with

```
`from schema.tableA`
```

I tried to get the procedure name in the get_ddl, but in vain
Basically for the given task name , get the proc_name in the get_ddl and then update the proc

```
with proc_name as (select procedure_name as proc_name from information_schema.procedures WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME in
              (select upper(rtrim(col)) from (
  select distinct replace(replace(replace(replace(query_text,'CALL ',''),'(null,',''),'null)',''),'BASE.','')as col 
                from table (information_schema.TASK_HISTORY(TASK_NAME => 'TASK_MERGE')))))
SELECT GET_DDL('procedure',(select concat('''',proc_name,'(varchar,varchar)','''') from proc));
```

Comment: Wrap the get_ddl and update in a stored procedure

Comment: @NickW I tried to get_ddl but in vain

Comment: What does that mean? Did it error and if so what error message? Did it not return what you were expecting and if so what were the differences? Did you include any parameters that the SPs take? Please update your question with the code you have managed to write, as editable text

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute via python